# Java logging do not execute info when level is severe

Tags: java, logging

I'm using `java.util.logging`

I have a foo function:

```
public String foo() {
    System.out.println("syso ==> foo");
    return "foo";
}
```

When I change the log level I don't wan't foo to be executed!

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getSimpleName());
FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("myapp.log");
logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
logger.info("Write foo: " + foo() );
logger.severe("Test severe");
```

I know that the `logger.info()` won't be printed in the log file, but why to execute `foo()`?
How can I solve it?

Thank's

Comment: "*I'm seeking for one line solution*" > why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it doesn't display that text, the line does get executed, because that line is not a comment.

If using Apache Logger, then try using `Logger.isInfoEnabled()` method this way:-

```
if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
    logger.info("Write foo: " + foo() );
}
```

Else, if its jdk logger, then use the below method as suggested by **@n1ckolas**

```
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
    logger.info("Write foo: " + foo() );
}
```

Comment: He seems to be using jdk1.4 Logger, and thus it should be `logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)`

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you disable info does not make the `logger.info` line "invisible" to the compiler and linker. This line is still going to execute and since you make a call to `foo` it will be executed as well.

You should use the Logger methods to check if info level is enabled and only than use `log.info`

If you are using apache logger than use :

```
if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("Write foo: " + foo() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Logger.info` expects a `String` argument.

`"Write foo: " + foo()` is getting converted to `String`, even before the logging level is checked inside the `info` method.

In this process `foo()` gets executed to get the `String` it returns.

To solve this you can use this construct:

```
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
    logger.info("Write foo: " + foo());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the `java.util.logging.*` classes.
Then this should do the trick:

```
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
    logger.info("Write foo: " + foo() );
}
```

If you are using Log4J, then use

```
if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("Write foo: " + foo() );
}
```

Comment: Finnaly, a legitimate reason to use this.. :)

Comment: @cowls Possibly - I'm wondering if the OP has posted a simple example that doesn't correpond to what is actually required. Hence [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15109348/474189) below, which might be more geared towards real use cases.

Comment: @DuncanJones Possibly, I think this approach is more logical. Putting any functional code in the toString method is a bit odd. This should really just be used for returning a String representation of the variable. (Lets say method foo() is reading state from a database for example). Doesnt make sense for that to be in a toString() method

Comment: If you want it in one line you can extract it to your own method. Personally I dont think thats necessary unless you use it everywhere

Comment: In one line, but this checks the level twice and looks a bit weirdish: logger.info(logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO) ? "Write foo: " + foo() : "");